# C# UWP: Using .NET Framework targetted References

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, .net-framework-version, windowsiot

I am migrating a Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework) program to a Universal Windows Platform program for a Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT on it.

I need to use a 3D CAD mouse with my program and the mouse company's SDK has sample code for C# which only works with .NET Framework. However the UWP targets .NET Core

I tried implementing Windows' solution to target .NET Framework : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

I did the following: 
Rightclick on project name > Unload Project > Rightclick on project name > Edit
Then I added the following code in the XML Project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net40</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

When I reload the project, the "References" tab is gone so I replaced "TargetFramework" with "IncludeFramework". The "References" tab is back but I still can't add my third party .dll file.

How can I use .NET Framework targeted references with my UWP program for raspberry Pi?

Comment: If the 3rd party library is **only** targeting .net framework, then you **cannot** use it in UWP. Does the library target other frameworks?

Comment: I am not sure but when I try adding the .dll file the following error appears:
A reference to "file address" could not be added. The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario

Comment: So if possible you need to get the source code to build the .net core version, or use another library instead which supports .net core runtime.